# How to use simplehtmldom to parse and look for a table

Tags: php, html, html-table, echo, simple-html-dom

I have this set of html table
`<table width=250 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 bgcolor=#F9F400>`
which has more td and tr tags with `<tr>` tags as well.

and I have this PHP expression `echo $html->find(''table td[bgcolor=#F9F400]');`

but there's nothing echoed and there's no error logged, is this the wrong method to do this? I would like to display the whole table as it is.

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 0):

From the html given:

```
<table width=250 border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 bgcolor=#F9F400>
```

You need to select the table whose `bgcolor` is `#F9F400`. You are currently selecting the `td` elements that have the background color. To get the table, try :

```
$table = $html->find('table[bgcolor=#F9F400]', 0);
```

The `0` indicates you want the first result, otherwise you will get an array returned. You can then `echo` the table, which will automatically convert the object to a string;

```
echo $table;
```

If you want to get all the `td` elements inside the table:

```
$tds = $table->find('td');
```

Note this will return an array, and so you would need to loop through them to print their content. Similar to what you wrote, you could do it like:

```
// get all tds of table with bgcolor #F9F400
$tds = $html->find('table[bgcolor=#F9F400] td');
foreach ($tds as $td) {
    // do what you like with the td
    echo $td;
}
```

Comment: Doug: That was a no go, somehow echoing from the php section does not help neither at the body tag with a php tag. There's no output from there, anyway to see if its parsing correctly?

Comment: @eddy You can try `$table = $html->find('table');` and the `echo count($table);` to see if anything is matched.